# Python: Get all data from database and write csv

Tags: python, django, csv

I want to get all data from database and write a csv. But I can't get data by using this **user.lrn** (for example). But if I try to remove the lrn and just use **user**, I only got all lrn. I don't know how to call the other field. Below is my code for the write csv function.

*views.py*

```
def exportStudentList(request):
    user = Student.objects.all()
    data = [user.lrn, user.lastname]
    # data = [user]
    field = ['LRN', 'Last Name']

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Students.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(field)  # Header
    writer.writerows(data)  # Rows

    return response
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes that you have a Django model called Student with fields lrn and lastname. It creates a CSV file with the headers "LRN" and "Last Name" and writes the data from the Student model to the file. The HttpResponse object is used to return the CSV file as a response to the user's request.

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse
from myapp.models import Student

def exportStudentList(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Students.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['LRN', 'Last Name'])
    for student in students:
        writer.writerow([student.lrn, student.lastname])
    return response
```